# "Abstract nonsense" -- does it have negative meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Is the collocation "abstract nonsense" coloured somehow in negative way? I mean mostly the second word -- can it mean "something too strange to be good" or something like this, and in what context?

Comment: Either word on its own can be used in a somewhat negative sense.  For "nonsense" that's fairly common.  If something were described to me as "abstract nonsense" I would likely take it as negative and dismissive: "Don't bother with Smith.  He writes nothing but abstract nonsense."

Comment: 'nonsense' rather is _not_ positive. In the mathematical contexts where you'd see this phrase (in discussions of category theory), you're more likely to expect this phrase to be disparaging. But it may also be used in a backwards way, almost sarcastically, as a compliment.

Comment: In category theory, abstract nonsense and general abstract nonsense describe a type of proof which offers little insight into the objects under consideration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_nonsense The description is neither positive or negative, it's true or false.

Comment: "something too strange to be good" is rather negative, don't you think? It means it is NOT GOOD